# Android Create Custom Keyboard

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

[image]

**Board**

[image: 2]

I want to create a custom keyboard like below, where the icon will be there in suggestions, on clicking that will open a separate view in the key I attached screens, I don't know how to start

[image]

And also there should be a edit text in it.
[image]

I should be able to enter text in both places

Comment: u can achiv this think by changing keybord layout

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki thanks for your suggestion , if you have any example please share it will be helpful

Comment: make clear that u want to create own keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/AnkitDroidGit/Android-Custom-Keyboard)
is custom keyboard sample, You can get the idea about how to start

Comment: @ramakrishna thanks , i want to customize the keyboard view

Comment: @Shanmugam There is no way to do that.  You can write a totally custom keyboard, but there's no way to override the layout of an existing one.